# Improper rational/trig integral comes out to $\pi/e$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

During my studying to integration I find this integration.  So I tried to prove but I got stuk.  So I need help in this integration. 
$$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (x)}{1+x^2}  dx = \frac {\pi}{e} $$

Comment: Have you considered using power series  representation

Comment: you say you did get stuck where did you get stuck?

Comment: This is easy using complex analysis and the residue theorem.  If that is beyond you, then it is a tough one.

Comment: Are you supposed to know the sine and cosine integral functions ?

Comment: @Bort  During the proof

Comment: @RonGordon could you explain more...

Comment: If you are familiar and know what I am talking about, I will be happy to outline a solution using that method.  If not, then it will be of no use to you.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes l know sin and cos Integral functions.  But I couldn't use them it solve

Comment: it would be rather hard getting stuck before you start or after you finished, wouldn't it? I was asking for you to give some details about how you tried to show it and where this lead you. Also you say you found it studying, then probably you found it with some context which might give a clue on how the problem is intended to be tackled ( personally I think @RonGordon hinted in the right direction )

Comment: @RonGordon  could you please post the solution

Answer (score 4):

Consider the contour integral

$$ \oint_C dz \frac{z e^{i z}}{1+z^2}$$

where $C$ is a semicircle in the upper half plane of radius $R$.  Then the contour integral is equal to

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \frac{x e^{i x}}{1+x^2} + i R \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{R e^{i \theta} \, e^{i R e^{i \theta}}}{1+R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}}$$

As $R \to \infty$, the magnitude of the second integral is bounded by

$$\frac{R^2}{R^2-1} \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}} \le \frac{2 R^2}{R^2-1} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{R} $$

and thus vanishes in that limit.  Thus, by the residue theorem, the first integral on the LHS is $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of the integrand of the contour integral at the pole $z=i$, or

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{x e^{i x}}{1+x^2} = i 2 \pi \frac{i e^{-1}}{2 i} = i \frac{\pi}{e}$$

The result sought is found by taking the imaginary part of the above result.

Comment: Perfect sir.  Impressive solution

Answer (score 2):

*This is too long for a comment and it could be off-topic.*

There is no doubt that Ron Gordon's solution is the most elegant for this problem.

I have been thinking about sine and cosine integral functions (see my early comment) just because $$\frac x{1+x^2}=\frac 12 \Big(\frac 1{x-i}+\frac 1{x+i}\Big)$$ and $$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x+a}\,dx=\cos (a) \text{Si}(a+x)-\sin (a) \text{Ci}(a+x)$$ Combining all of that leads to $$\int \frac{x \sin (x)}{1+x^2}\,  dx=\frac{i \left(e^2-1\right) \big(\text{Ci}(i-x)-\text{Ci}(i+x)\big)-\left(e^2+1\right)
   \big(\text{Si}(i-x)+ \text{Si}(i+x)\big)}{4 e}$$ and then the result after using the bounds.